# ¿Como implemento un Switch Case con Radio Button en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, radiobutton, switch

Estoy haciendo una mini calculadora que me calcule el 5% de descuento de algunos productos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cree dos radio button "SI" y "NO":

```
        <label style="font-size: medium;">Descuento 5%:</label>
        <label style="padding-left: 10pt;">SI</label>
        <input type="radio" name="SN" id="SI">
        <label>NO</label>
        <input type="radio" name="SN" id="NO">
```

Esta es la funcion que estoy creando para que me funcione pero no lo logro, lleva mas case pero con uno solo creo que es suficiente para resolverme este problema, es mi primera vez implementando esto por lo cual no poseo conocimientos al respecto.

```
function Calcular(){
    var cod = document.getElementById("Productos").value;
    var cod = document.getElementById("SN").value;
    switch(cod){
        case '1':
            if (document.getElementById('SI').checked) {
                var x = '15';
                var y = parseInt( document.getElementById('Unidades').value);
                var z = '0.05';
                var r;
                var des;
                r = x * y;
                des = r * z;
                document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = r -des;
            } else if(document.getElementById('NO').checked){ 
            var x = '15';
            var y = parseInt( document.getElementById('Unidades').value);
            document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = x * y;
            }
            break;
```

Comment: El valor de `cod` es siempre el último que asignas. ¿Porqué asignarlo 2 veces? De hecho lo declaras 2 veces con `var`, ¿Porqué?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes unos cuantos errores en tu código:

1. Por alguna razón estás sobrescribiendo el valor de la variable cod.
2. No estás declarando el valor de los inputs radio. ¿Que valor pretendes leer si no estás declarando ningún valor?
3. Los precios, descuentos y cantidades los estás declarando como strings ¿Por qué?

Te adjunto un ejemplo funcional similar a tu código para que puedas implementar lo que quieres.

1. Primero seleccionas los inputs descuento, precio y cantidad y tomas su valor.
2. Preguntas luego por el descuento. Si no hay nada seleccionado no aplicas descuento, si la opción SI está seleccionada si lo aplicas.
3. Finalmente actualizas el resultado en la vista.

```js
 function calcular() {
    const precio = document.getElementById('precio').value
    const cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value
    const descuento = document.querySelector('input[name="descuento"]:checked') || 'No';
    const total = document.getElementById('total')

    let resultado;
    if(descuento.value == 'Si') {
      resultado = precio*cantidad*0.95
    }else{
      resultado = precio*cantidad
    }

    total.innerHTML = resultado.toFixed(2);
  }
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Descuento 5%:</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="descuento" value="Si" required>Si</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="descuento" value="No">No</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Precio</label>
    <input type="number" name="precio" id="precio" required min="0" >
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Cantidad</label>
    <input type="number" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" required min="0" count="1">
  </div>

  <button  onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>

<div>
  Total: <span id="total"></span>
</div>
```

Alternativamente puedes implementar un switch case con varios productos especificando el precio de cada producto:

```js
function calcular() {
      const productos = document.getElementById('productos').value;
      const cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value
      const descuento = document.querySelector('input[name="descuento"]:checked') || 'No';
      const total = document.getElementById('total')

      let resultado;
      let precio;

      switch (productos) {
        case 'producto 1':
          precio = 15
          if (descuento.value == 'Si')
            resultado = precio * cantidad * 0.95
          else
            resultado = precio * cantidad
        break
        
        case 'producto 2':
          precio = 20
          if (descuento.value == 'Si')
            resultado = precio * cantidad * 0.95
          else
            resultado = precio * cantidad
      }
      total.innerHTML = resultado.toFixed(2);
    }


    // Actualiza la etiqueta del producto cuando cambia
    function actualizarPrecio() {
      const productos = document.getElementById('productos').value;
      const precioLabel = document.getElementById('precio')
      let precio;
      switch (productos) {
        case 'producto 1':
          precio = 15
        break
        
        case 'producto 2':
          precio = 20
      }
      precioLabel.innerHTML = precio
    }

    actualizarPrecio()
```

```html
  <select name="productos" id="productos" onchange="actualizarPrecio()">
    <option value="producto 1" selected="selected">Producto 1</option>
    <option value="producto 2">Producto 2</option>
  </select>


  <div>
    <label>Descuento</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="descuento" value="Si" required>Si</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="descuento" value="No">No</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Precio: <span id="precio"></span></p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Cantidad</label>
    <input type="number" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" required min="0" count="1">
  </div>

  <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>

  <div>
    Total: <span id="total"></span>
  </div>
```